# Here’s a challenge

Tags: engine

My car is making a rapid clicking sound. It sounds like it is coming from the dash and the sound is much louder inside than outside. This only happens once the car is turned off. It does this off and on till the car is started up again. The. It stops with in a minute. The sound is best compared to a wood pecker but on speed or meth.

Comment: Has it always done this? If not, when did it start? What kind of car is it?

Comment: Next time you shut your car down, turn off the HVAC system (all the way off, not just the fan) and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: Some cars have a small grille (about 1/2" square) with a tiny fan to sense the internal cabin temperature - that might be the source...

Comment: It’s been doing this for about a month. At first it only happened when I started the car. Then it moved to doing what it’s doing now. I have a 2013 impala. Even with the air off it does it after the car gets shut down.